# schemadb + ZendFramework integration for rapid database growup in development time

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, database-schema

Hi i want integrate schemadb with ZendFramework to perform automatic database schema adapting when change Zend Models
https://sourceforge.net/p/schemadb/wiki/Home/

(ex.)

```
class Product extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {
    public $ID = [[ define as a primary key ]]
    .
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a more supported and documented system, you may want to [use doctrine2 with ZF1](https://github.com/guilhermeblanco/zendframework1-doctrine2). Then you will just be able to use [doctrine migrations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/latest/reference/introduction.html) and whatsoever.